# how to add/follow friends on a social networking site using jsp

Tags: mysql, jsp

I am working on a social networking site and my current problem is; I want the user to add or follow friends and I don't know how to execute it using mysql. I work with jsp pages.

Comment: Add some more details. And show us what have you tried till now. And how are you willing to achieve the task!

Comment: I have already created a table named user(with usernames, emails etc.). I thought of creating nested tables -so that there would be an extra column "friends" that would contain a list of friends- but that is not executable on mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's suppose you have a user table like this:

```
users(id, facebook_id, twitter_id, name, username, email, password)
```

Let's suppose you have a social network table like this:

```
social_networks(id, name)
```

Then you should have records in social_networks for `'facebook'` and `'twitter'`. Then, your `facebook_id` and `twitter`_id from the `users` table should be foreign keys to the `social_networks` table. Finally, you should have a friend table, like this:

```
friends(id, from_id, to_id, social_network_id)
```

where `from_id` and `to_id` is a `foreign key` to the `users` table and `social_network_id` is a foreign key to the `social_networks` table. This is how you handle the relation, as a person can have more friends and a person can be friend to more persons.

Comment: Thanks for the idea!! The site I am working on is a site like Facebook, so the social_networks table is unnecessary. Also, on the friends table the columns from_id and to_id must only contain one element (because that's how mysql works). I think I don't actually get it

Comment: No, that is not how mysql works. You can have multiple columns and multiple foreign keys.

Comment: Yes I know, but I understood that on the from and to columns you meant that there would be more than 1 elements(for more than 1 friends)

Comment: A friends record represents an instance of the friend concept. from_id is the friend of to_id. Nothing stops you from having many records in the friends table, as from_id and to_id does not need to be unique. Your only unique field in the friends table should be the id, which should also be a primary key.

Comment: For example;
id (Bob)     from_id  (Bob)    to_id (John)
id (???)     from_id  (Bob)    to_id (Mark)

I put ??? because Bob in column id must only appear once. The idea you suggest is for following or adding friends? By following I mean, that Bob can follow John, but it is not necessary that John also follows Bob.

Comment: id should be a number, unique for each record, just define it as id int primary key auto_increment. It does not relate to the users. from_id and to_id are the foreign keys used for that purpose. The friends table in my answer is not symmetrical. If Bob's friend is Mark, then Mark is not necessarily a friend of Bob. If you have a pair of (from_id, to_id), there is no guarantee that you have a reverse pair as well.

Comment: I am happy I was able to help.